# How does eth2 Random Election Work?

Tags: randomness, eth-2.0, validators, block-production, attestations

In eth2 validators will be randomly selected. What is the formula for how this random selection works?

Comment: The starting point is https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/core/0_beacon-chain.md#randao  If you or anyone figures it out, please explain it in a well-written answer.

Answer (score 2):

Validators are not randomly selected, anyone/thing with 32 ETH is eligible to become an Eth2 validator.

However, once a validator (represented by a BLS public key) becomes [active](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#is_active_validator), they are randomly selected to perform tasks on the beacon chain. There are two primary tasks:

- **Producing blocks**: the [compute_proposer_index](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#compute_proposer_index) function uses entropy from [randao reveals](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#randao) from previous blocks (and an eth1 block hash) to elect validators to produce blocks at certain heights in the beacon chain (these heights are known as "slots" in eth2).
- **Producing attestations**: the [get_beacon_committee](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#get_beacon_committee) function uses the same randao reveals to assign groups of validators into "committees" that must create attestations (votes) about the history of the beacon chain. In phase 1/2, these committees will likely also attest to properties of shard chains.

*Cavet: the Eth2 spec is still evolving, this answer references spec v0.11.1 from April 2020*

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83553/how-are-block-proposers-selected-in-ethereum-2-0