# How are block proposers selected in Ethereum 2.0?

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, beacon-chain, block-production

i'm doing some research about Ethereum 2.0 for university. I think i understand the way it works, but i have a perplexity about the proposer selection in a slot, especially after reading the codes here: https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs

From what i understand, at the beginning of a slot a validator check whether he's a proposer or not by using the *compute_proposer_index*, which takes as parameter the beacon state, a sequence of validator and the seed. In general all informations come from the beacon state: slot, epoch, randao_mixes, list of active validators...

My question is: assuming that the state change only with a block (like eth 1), **if a proposer doesn't send a block during its slot, maintaining the same state, how is the next proposer selected? Shouldn't the random variables remain the same, causing the election of the same proposer over and over until he sends out a block?**

Example: i'm at slot 500 and so the state is set at Slot: 500; from the informations i got in the state the next proposer should be X, but at slot 501 X goes offline and the state is unchanged: if at slot 502 i run again the code i should get X again, since nothing changed, and the blockchain gets stuck until X comes back online.

Ofc is not like this, i'm missing something, i just can't see what. Can you help me? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> if a proposer doesn't send a block during its slot, maintaining the same state, how is the next proposer selected?

The same state isn't maintained, each slot has a different state. The [get_beacon_proposer_index](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#get_beacon_proposer_index) function uses `state.slot` to seed the proposer shuffling.

If a proposer fails to publish a block at slot `n`, then the proposer for the next slot will build their block upon a state with slot `n + 1`.

> Example: i'm at slot 500 and so the state is set at Slot: 500; from the informations i got in the state the next proposer should be X, but at slot 501 X goes offline and the state is unchanged: if at slot 502 i run again the code i should get X again, since nothing changed, and the blockchain gets stuck until X comes back online.

In your example, your head block has `block.slot == 500`. This means the `state` represented by `block.state_root` will also have `state.slot == 500`.

Before the proposer for `slot == 502` produces a block they will call [`process_slots(state, 502)`](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#beacon-chain-state-transition-function), increasing `state.slot` from `500` to `502`.

If the proposer for `slot == 501` had produced a block, they would have called `process_slots(state, 501)`, which would result in a different result when calling `get_beacon_proposer_index(state)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Example: i'm at slot 500 and so the state is set at Slot: 500; from the informations i got in the state the next proposer should be X, but at slot 501 X goes offline and the state is unchanged: if at slot 502 i run again the code i should get X again, since nothing changed, and the blockchain gets stuck until X comes back online.

Although validators add to RANDAO in each slot, the global RANDAO value is only updated once per epoch. To compute the index of the next block proposer, the RANDAO value is mixed with the slot number to give a unique value in each slot (taken from [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pos/block-proposal/)).

I hope this finally answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

[The specification](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/validator.md#preparing-for-a-beaconblock) says:

> The parent selected must satisfy that parent.slot < block.slot.

There is no requirement that `parent.slot` must be `block.slot - 1`. So the validator will simply choose newest block which was produced in an earlier slot.

Then it's explicitly stated:

> Note: There might be "skipped" slots between the parent and block

Comment: Your explaining that slots can be "skipped", but not how the next proposer is selected.